# Associate parameterized fixture with parameterized test in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I want to do something similar to this in pytest (this is just a simplified example):

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=['A', 'B'])
def fixture1(request):
    return request.param.lower()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("extra_arg1", ["1", "2"])
def test_xxx(fixture1, extra_arg1):
    assert fixture1 + extra_arg1 == ..... 
    # the test is expected to run 4 times and the results should be "a1", "b1", "a2", "b2"
```

How can I associate the parameterized fixture with the parameters in the test?
Note: I have to use fixture because it has been already in place in the project repo.

Thank you!

Comment: this doesn't make much sense, you're trying to assert the outcome of a fixture instead of testing some other function in your actual codebase

Comment: This would just work if you would use `request` instead of `arg` in `fixture1`.What is `arg` supposed to be?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen sorry, I just changed ```arg``` to ```request```. I'm still not sure how I can define the assert statement

Comment: Difficult to say without understanding what you want to achieve. The test in your question makes no sense, as it tests only the parameters, so I guess you have some functionality you want to test depending on these parameters. Generally speaking, the expected test results shall go together with the parameters, but in your case it it not clear where do you get the result for the fixture. Maybe you can provide a bit more information about your actual use case.